# How can I create an onscreen controller that works in multiple scenes in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Working on a game in SpriteKit to learn. Its a platformer with an onscreen controller. I have this all working using touchesBegan and touchesEnded to know when the player is pushing the buttons or not. This works fine, however when i want to load the next scene for 'level 2' i need to implement the controller all over again. I could do a lot of copy and pasting but I feel this will lead to a lot of duplication of code. Every tutorial I've ever read said to try to adhere to the DRY principle.

Im sorry if this is simple, but I have <6 months programming experience and am trying to learn and improve. Im assuming I would need to create a separate class for the onscreen controller so it can be reused, but Im a little lost on where to start.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = (touch.location(in: playerCamera))
        print("LocationX: \(location.x), LocationY: \(location.y)")
        let objects = nodes(at: location)
        print("\(objects)")
        if  rightButton.frame.contains(location) {

            rightButtonPressed = true
            playerFacingRight = true
            playerFacingLeft = false
            thePlayer.xScale = 1
            let animation = SKAction(named: "running")!
            let loopingAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)
            thePlayer.run(loopingAnimation, withKey: "moveRight")
            moveRight()
          } else if leftButton.frame.contains(location) {
            leftButtonPressed = true
            playerFacingLeft = true
            playerFacingRight = false
            thePlayer.xScale = -1

            let leftAnimation = SKAction(named: "running")!
            let leftLoopingAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(leftAnimation)
            thePlayer.run(leftLoopingAnimation, withKey: "moveLeft")
            moveLeft()
          } else if upButton.frame.contains(location) {
            upButtonPressed = true
            print("upButton is pressed")

            if playerAndButtonContact == true {
                print("contact - player + button + upButtonPressed=true")
                print("\(movingPlatform.position)")
                button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "switchGreen")
                 let moveRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: -150, duration: 3)



            if movingPlatform.position == CGPoint(x: -355, y: movingPlatform.position.y) {
                    movingPlatform.run(moveRight)
                    thePlayer.run(moveRight)
                    button.run(moveRight)
                }

            }


            if playerAndDoorSwitchContact == true {

                let switchPressed = SKAction.run{
                    self.switchPressedSound()
                    self.doorSwitch.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "switchGreen")
                    self.door.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "DoorUnlocked")
                }

                let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)

                let doorOpen = SKAction.run {

                        let doorOpen = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "DoorOpen")
                        doorOpen.alpha = 0
                        doorOpen.position = self.door.position
                        doorOpen.size = self.door.size
                        doorOpen.size = self.door.size
                        self.door.zPosition = -2
                        doorOpen.zPosition = -1
                    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.5)
                        let start = SKAction.run {
                            self.addChild(doorOpen)
                            doorOpen.run(fadeIn)

                        }
                        let sound = SKAction.run {
                            self.doorOpeningSound()
                        }
                        let opening = SKAction.group([sound, start])
                    self.door.run(opening)

                    }

                    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([switchPressed, wait, doorOpen])


                self.doorSwitch.run(sequence)

                }

            if playerAndDoorContact == true {

                self.view?.presentScene(level1, transition: transition)

            }


          } else if downButton.frame.contains(location) {


          }
          else if shoot.frame.contains(location) {
            shoot()

          } else if jumpButton.frame.contains(location) {

            self.pressed = true

            let timerAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.05)

            let update = SKAction.run {
                if(self.force < Constants.maximumJumpForce) {
                    self.force += 2.0
                } else {
                    self.jump(force: Constants.maximumJumpForce)
                    self.force = Constants.maximumJumpForce


                }
            }

            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([timerAction, update])
            let repeat_seq = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
            self.run(repeat_seq, withKey: "repeatAction")
      }
}


}
```

Comment: use the container view and add your buttons(controllers) open the main view...

Comment: subcalss a SKNode that contains the buttons. Add it once you load the SKScene